# ImportError: Module 'pythoncom' isn't in frozen sys.path

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, pyttsx3, pythoncom

I tries to convert my `.py` file to `.exe` which uses `PYTTSX3` module through `PyInstaller` command and also imported hidden imports like `pyttsx3.drivers`, `pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5`.

Command used:

```
pyinstaller .\SCREENER.PY --hidden-import pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5 --hidden-import babel.numbers --hidden-import pythoncom
```

`SCREENER` is the name of my Python File*

But yet I'm getting this Error in my `.exe` file.

Please suggest me  something to handle this, as this is my Final Year project, so I have to get this sorted anyhow.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError with cx\_freeze and pywin32: Module 'pythoncom' isn't in frozen sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891071/importerror-with-cx-freeze-and-pywin32-module-pythoncom-isnt-in-frozen-sys-p)

Answer (score 0):

The error may be as a result of spurious imports in your environment. Just had the exact same error.

Tried a few things on the link Thingamabobs added, and others as well.

Ended up making a clean environment, then running pyInstaller via:

pyInstaller --onefile -- paths "D:\Anaconda3\envs<MyEnv>\Lib\site-packages" myScript.py

[, D:\Anaconda3\ and myScript obviously being adjusted to your use]

And the problem was gone.